# Move all clone elements to container

Tags: jquery

I'm working on a simple app that will put circles inside the boxes.
What I want is, to move all those circles to a new container, I tried to use same code but the direction is incorrect.

> you need to choose a circle then select one of the boxes, you can select again. after that, click on the 'move' to transfer all those
>   circles to that big box on top.

```js
var selectedCircle = null;

$(".circle").click(function() {
  $(this).addClass('selected').siblings().siblings('.clone').remove();
  $(this).addClass('selected').siblings().removeClass('selected').animate({
    top: 0,
    left: 0
  });
  selectedCircle = $(this);
});

$(".container .square").click(function() {

  if (selectedCircle) {
    
    $('.clone').removeClass('selected');
    var selectedSquare = $(this);
    debugger;
    var selectedCircleClone = selectedCircle.clone().addClass("clone");
    selectedCircle.after(selectedCircleClone);

    var xOffset = (selectedSquare.width() - selectedCircleClone.width()) / 2;
    var yOffset = (selectedSquare.height() - selectedCircleClone.height()) / 2;

    selectedCircleClone.animate({
      top: selectedSquare.offset().top - selectedCircleClone.offset().top + yOffset,
      left: selectedSquare.offset().left - selectedCircleClone.offset().left + xOffset
    }, 1200);
  }
});

$(".move").click(function() {
    var main = $('.main');
    var clones = $('.round .clone');
    var xOffset = (main.width() - clones.width()) / 2;
    var yOffset = (main.height() - clones.height()) / 2;

    clones.animate({
      top: main.offset().top - clones.offset().top + yOffset,
      left: main.offset().left - clones.offset().left + xOffset
    }, 1200);
});
```

```css
.main{
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #DDD;
  margin: 0 auto;
  
}

.container {
  height: 200px;
  width: 550px;
  background-color: #eee;
  padding: 10px;
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid #DDD;
  margin: auto;
}

.round {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 10px;
}

.square {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid #f60;
  position: relative;
}

.square:nth-child(2) {
  width: 65px;
}

.square:nth-child(3) {
  width: 75px;
}

.square:nth-child(4) {
  width: 85px;
}

.square:nth-child(5) {
  width: 95px;
}

.square:nth-child(6) {
  width: 105px;
}

.square:nth-child(7) {
  width: 115px;
}

.square:nth-child(8) {
  width: 125px;
}

.square .circle {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
}
.circle {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: absolute;
  width: 45px;
  height: 45px;
  border: 1px solid green;
  border-radius: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
}

.circle span {
  width: 10px;
  height: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin: auto;
}

.circle.selected {
  background-color: #FFFF;
}
.round .box{
  width: 45px;
  height: 45px;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
}
.move{
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #FFF;
  border: 1px solid #DDD;
  height: 30px;
  width: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main">
  
</div>


<div class="container">
  <div class="box">
    <div class="square"></div>
    <div class="square"></div>
    <div class="square"></div>
    <div class="square"></div>
    <div class="square"></div>
    <div class="square"></div>
    <div class="square"></div>
    <div class="square"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="round">
    <div class="box">
      <div class="circle">
      <span>1</span>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
      <div class="circle">
      <span>2</span>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
      <div class="circle">
      <span>3</span>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
      <div class="circle">
      <span>4</span>
    </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="move">MOVE</div>
</div>
```